# Python integrate input and output

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, printing, io

I have recently created a 2-way python chat using sockets in python. However, The client send terminal window and client receive window are separate (so I see the messages in one terminal window, and I type my response in another. This is because they're 2 different programs). My question is how can I add these two windows together so that I can both use the input function while messages are still being output to the screen. I think the answer is that it is impossible, and if that's the case what alternatives can I use.

Comment: Have you tried multithreading to run multiple functions concurrently in a single program? Also, can you give example of your current code?

Comment: That will work perfectly thank you, I did not know what threading was until I googled it just now.

Comment: If you have two truly separate programs, how does one program preclude the other from doing something? If they are *not* separate programs, then terminal emulator windows were never meant to be *components* of a single program, but the *host* for a single program.

Answer (score 0):

You could use threads from the `threading` module to run multiple functions in parallel.

Documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html